# Auto-detect USB Device Connect/Disconnect

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications, usb

I have a Cocoa app that needs to be notified whenever a device is connected or disconnected from a USB port. I can get the DeviceConnected callback to work, but the DeviceDisconnected function does not get called when disconnecting a USB device.

Below is my code:

```
+ (void)listenForUSBEvents
{
   io_iterator_t  portIterator = 0;
   CFMutableDictionaryRef  matchingDict = IOServiceMatching( kIOUSBDeviceClassName );
   IONotificationPortRef  notifyPort = IONotificationPortCreate( kIOMasterPortDefault );
   CFRunLoopSourceRef  runLoopSource = IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource( notifyPort );
   CFRunLoopRef  runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();

   CFRunLoopAddSource( runLoop, runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
   CFRetain( matchingDict );

   kern_return_t  returnCode = IOServiceAddMatchingNotification( notifyPort, kIOMatchedNotification, matchingDict, DeviceConnected, NULL, &portIterator );

   if ( returnCode == 0 )
   {
      DeviceConnected( nil, portIterator );
   }

   returnCode = IOServiceAddMatchingNotification( notifyPort, kIOMatchedNotification, matchingDict, DeviceDisconnected, NULL, &portIterator );

   if ( returnCode == 0 )
   {
      DeviceDisconnected( nil, portIterator );
   }
}

@end


void DeviceConnected( void *refCon, io_iterator_t iterator )
{
   kern_return_t  returnCode = KERN_FAILURE;
   io_object_t  usbDevice;

   while ( ( usbDevice = IOIteratorNext( iterator ) ) )
   {
     io_name_t name;

     returnCode = IORegistryEntryGetName( usbDevice, name );

     if ( returnCode != KERN_SUCCESS )
     {
        return;
     }

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:deviceConnectedNotification object:nil userInfo:nil];
   }
}

void DeviceDisconnected( void *refCon, io_iterator_t iterator )
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:deviceDiconnectedNotification object:nil userInfo:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.

First of all, IOServiceAddMatchingNotification for deviceDisconnected should look like this:

```
returnCode = IOServiceAddMatchingNotification( notifyPort, kIOTerminatedNotification, matchingDict, DeviceDisconnected, NULL, &portIterator );
```

Second, the DeviceDisconnected function should look like this:

```
void DeviceDisconnected( void *refCon, io_iterator_t iterator )
{
    kern_return_t    returnCode = KERN_FAILURE;
    io_object_t      usbDevice;

    while ( ( usbDevice = ioIteratorNext( iterator ) ) )
    {
        returnCode = IOObjectRelease( usbDevice );

        if ( returnCode != kIOReturnSuccess )
        {
            NSLog( @"Couldn't release raw device object: %08x.", returnCode );
        }
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:deviceDiconnectedNotification object:nil userInfo:nil];
}
```